# If $f$ is continuous ,$F_n$ is pointwise convergent to $f$ and $F_n$ is uniformly convergent...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f$ is continuous ,$F_n$ is pointwise convergent to $f$ and $F_n$ is uniformly convergent. Then $F_n$ in uniformly convergent to $f$.

To me, this result makes perfect sense. But I can not seem to find it in my analysis notes.

Is this implication correct?

Comment: Have you tried to prove the negation? Maybe you will immediately get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F_n$ converges uniformly to a function $g$, then it is also pointwise convergent to $g$. Since $F_n$ is also pointwise convergent to $f$, we have $f=g$ (pointwise limit is unique).

Answer (score 0):

Your implication is correcto. Suppose that the sequence converges uniformly to a función $g$ and show that for all $\epsilon>0$, and $x$ in the domain, the difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is less than $\epsilon$. What can we conclude?